# How to know what exception should be throws when I edit any piece of java code

Tags: java, vim

Recently, I used the VIM development program. 
It greatly improved my programming efficiency, but VIM lacks the prompt function of the IDE. 
When doing exception handling, I don't even know what exception the current code should throw.

My problem is, instead of relying on the IDE to write code, how do we determine what exceptions should be thrown by the code?

I am not referring to the exception that a particular class wants to throw, but the exception handling I might encounter during the encoding process. 
Therefore no specific code is attached.

Comment: Read a class reference. With time you will remember more and more of what is thrown, but generally you should always consult a class reference.

Comment: @mrunion Yes, I tried to check the JDK related documentation to confirm how to handle the exception, but in fact, the effect is not very good, is there any specific method?

Comment: @mrunion If java supports polymorphism, then I don't know if exception handling can use the base class of all exceptions.

Comment: Then I must be misunderstanding your question. But again, a Java reference should tell you the answer to that question for sure, but I would think you can catch any error that would be thrown. And you should be able to catch all errors (but that is not recommended -- you should only catch errors in code that you can handle in that code).

Comment: Basically each class has defined the type of exception it will throw. If it is checked exception like IOException etc then the IDE will give an error if you don't handle this exception. Secondly nowadays IDE is a must have tool for any type of development. You can't be more productive without it.

Comment: @mrunion Maybe it's not that you misunderstood, my English is not very good, and it may be ambiguous. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz Yes, after trying to edit the java code with VIM in the past few days, I gradually felt that I should re-use the IDE (in fact, for the development of JavaScript, it is very convenient to use VIM).Thank you！

Comment: @时间只会一直走 I would recommend using JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA for Java Development. It is much more convenient!